# Using the Shopify API in the Front-End

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, shopify

I’m building a stand-alone Web App built in Javascript (React + Redux to be specific). I’ve had great success using the Shopify Buy SDK to pull in data **from** my Shopify store. However, as I need to use the [**main** Shopify API][2] to add products and other advanced features that the Buy SDK doesn’t support.

I can successfully connect to the Shopify API from the server side (using NodeJS), but when I try and do the same connection in the Front-End (I of course retrieve the app keys and secret tokens through my .env environment variable for security reasons):

```
axios.get('https://<app-key>:<app-password>@rmc-preview.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json').then((data) => {
  console.log('data: ', data);
});
```

, then I get a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://rmc-preview.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I'd like to connect both through my localhost as well as my public site (currently hosted through Netlify).

Do I need to connect with this API through server-side, or is it at all possible to connect through the Front-End?

Appreciate any tips or advice you have.

Comment: does that endpoint support jsonp?

Comment: I'll ask Shopify now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke such a thing on Shopify front-end for all the security matters. CORS and stuff. You need to route the request through a backend app that can utilize the API.

Node.js is something you are looking at right.

Comment: Never mind the CORS issue. It is straight up a terrible idea to think about accessing the API from public facing code, as it exposes your API secret to the world. To accomplish any API shenanigans, install an App, and then use the built-in secure App Proxy pattern to proxy your front-end calls.

Comment: Thanks David! I am not actually exposing any API secrets to the public as they are being defined in a .env file - both localhost as well as on the live server. That's why I thought it may be doable to do through the front-end.

Comment: Hi @DavidLazar, could you provide a link to a web page showing how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

Even though your keys are in .env they get packaged up and are opened on the front end.  You need to go the server API route
https://youtu.be/FcwfjMebjTU

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31993756)